# How to transform simple CSS box

Tags: css, css-shapes

I have a simple box. I need to transform it like in the image. Is there a way to do it with CSS?

[image]

```
.box-wrapper{
    border: 3px solid #fff;
    width: 397px;
    height: 130px;
}
```

Comment: 2 seconds on google gives me this example http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_transform

Comment: this is the most basic thing you could have got from css3 beginners tutorial try search for `skew` in w3schools http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_transform_skew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `transform: skewY(20deg)` to do this. You should also consider the transform origin (the point on the element from where the transformation is calculated). In this case I have set it be `transform-origin: top left;`

```
.box-wrapper{
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  width: 397px;
  height: 130px;
  background: #000;
  transform: skewY(20deg); 
  transform-origin: top left;   
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daynsxLt/3/

Comment: I think you need to mention `transform-origin` as well. Currently it is cutting-off the screen.

Comment: Updated answer to use transform origin.

Answer (score 2):

```css
.box-wrapper {
  background: black none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  height: 130px;
  transform: skew(0, 15deg);
  width: 397px;
  transform-origin: left center 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-wrapper"></div>
```